# UIAlertView adding NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uialertview

I want to add string to message of my UIAlertView

```
-(void) errorState:(NSException *) exp
{
    NSLog(@"Error State Blood Level3 %@",exp);
    NSString * myString = (NSString*)exp;
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:myString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Go to the main menu" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
```

}

but it throws

```
2010-07-15 12:48:34.721 kndFrameV02[7955:207] -[NSException isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x707b2e0
2010-07-15 12:48:34.724 kndFrameV02[7955:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSException isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x707b2e0'
```

so how can i add string variable to the message of UIAlertView?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `NSException` won't suddenly turn into an `NSString` when you cast it as one. `NSException` has a property called `reason`, that's the one you need. Use it like this: `NSString *reason = exp.reason;`